# Почему сортировка по цене не работает?

Tags: javascript

В методе `sortProductsByPrice (sortOrder)` сортировка не работает, когда я удаляю или добавляю продукты в dom при помощи слушателей(`buttAdd.addEventListener`,`buttDelete.addEventListener`), сортировка работает только для продуктов, находящихся в массиве `this.products` по умолчанию.

**(Продукты сортируются, при клике на `<th> Price: </ th>`.**

Необходимо, чтобы сортировка также работала после удаления / добавления товаров.

*Я пробовал переместить всех слушателей с их переменными в метод `show()`, но  после этого когда срабатывает  buttAdd.addEventListener добавляется продукт, при следующем добавлении то количество, которое уже было добавлено и +1, а фильтр по цене все равно не работал :)*

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    //method for remove product by name
    deleteProductByName(productName) {
        let i = this.products.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // get total price by all products
    get totalProductsPrice() {
        return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    }

    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
        const sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
        });
        this.products = sorted;
    }

    // method to draw the table with product property (
    // name, count, price)
    show() {
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
        const table = document.getElementById("shop");
        const tFoot = table.querySelector('tfoot');
        if (tFoot) tFoot.remove();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            //create table
            table.innerHTML += `<tbody><tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr></tbody>`;
        }
        //show total price by all products
        table.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td colspan="3" id="total-price">Total price: 
        ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr></tfoot>`;
    }
}
// add new product by click
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value),
        parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value)));
    shop.show();
}, false);
// delete product by name after click
const formDelete = document.forms[1];
const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    shop.deleteProductByName(nameDelete.value);
    shop.show();
}, false);
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 2, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 3, 1000));
shop.show();
const priceFilter = document.getElementById("filter");
//filter products by price
priceFilter.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    shop.show();
}, false);
console.log(shop.products);
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
    <div class="add-product">
        <h1>Add product</h1>
        <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<div class="product-table">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <form id="delete-form">
        <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
        <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <table id="shop">
        <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th id="filter">Price:</th>
            <th>Count:</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, сортировка не сработала вообще или не сработала правильно?
Как вариант, `a.price > b.price` не работает для строк. Поэтому лучше заменить условие сравнения цены на `(sortOrder == Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC) ? a.price - b.price : b.price - a.price`

Comment: Сортировка не работает для новых товаров, то есть когда я  кликаю по полю <th> Price: </ th в ново созданной таблице с значениями с массива по умолчанию, то сортировка работает, но когда  добавляю или удаляю  товары  перезаписывается html таблицы и клик  уже не рабочий

Answer (score 1):

Что-то с построением таблицы, немного поправил

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
  constructor(name, count, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
  constructor() {
    this.products = [];
  }

  //method for adding a product
  addProduct(newProduct) {
    this.products.push(newProduct);
  }

  //method for remove product by name
  deleteProductByName(productName) {
    let i = this.products.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
        this.products.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  // get total price by all products
  get totalProductsPrice() {
    return this.products.map(product => product.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
  }

  //method for sorting the product at its price
  sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
    const sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
    });
    this.products = sorted;
  }

  // method to draw the table with product property (
  // name, count, price)
  show() {
    const table = document.getElementById("shop");
    const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      //create table
      tbody.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr></tbody>`;
    }
    //show total price by all products
    tbody.innerHTML += `<tfoot><tr><td colspan="3" id="total-price">Total price: 
        ${shop.totalProductsPrice}</td></tr>`;
  }
}
// add new product by click
const formAdd = document.forms[0];
const inputsAdd = formAdd.elements;
const buttAdd = formAdd.elements[3];
buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  shop.addProduct(new Product(inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(inputsAdd[2].value),
    parseInt(inputsAdd[1].value)));
  shop.show();
}, false);
// delete product by name after click
const formDelete = document.forms[1];
const nameDelete = formDelete.elements[0];
const buttDelete = formDelete.elements[1];
buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  shop.deleteProductByName(nameDelete.value);
  shop.show();
}, false);
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 2, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 3, 1000));
shop.show();
const priceFilter = document.getElementById("filter");
//filter products by price
priceFilter.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
  shop.show();
}, false);
console.log(shop.products);
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
  <div class="add-product">
    <h1>Add product</h1>
    <form id="addForm">
      <label for="name">Name of product</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="input-product">
      <label for="price">Price of product</label>
      <input type="text" id="price" class="input-product">
      <label for="count">Count of product</label>
      <input type="text" id="count" class="input-product">
      <button id="add">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="product-table">
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <form id="delete-form">
      <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
      <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <table id="shop">
      <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name:</th>
          <th id="filter">Price:</th>
          <th>Count:</th>
        </tr>
        <thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли  сортировка работает по клику на <th> Price: </ th>,  она работает при создании таблицы  с товарами по умолчанию, но кода я  удаляю или добавляю товар, html таблицы  перезаписывается  и клик  по <th> Price: </ th> уже не рабочий то есть товары не сортируются. Я пробовал это решить добавлениям слушателей и их переменных в метод show()? но не помогло, я описал это наверху

Comment: Вы забрали  цикл  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
При котором перезаписывается строка  с  параметрами товара, после того как вы ее забрали, она перетирает  прошлый html в виде заголовков